# Rails 3 and RSpec: Clickable file paths in errors messages (in OSX Terminal)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rspec, terminal

It's nice to have so much information about failing specs when using RSpec for testing my Rails3 app, but it would be even nicer to have them clickable:

`` 2) Project 
     Failure/Error: create(:project) # Needed for validate_presence_of
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name has already been taken
     # ./spec/models/project_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' ``

So when clicking on `./spec/models/project_spec.rb:6` this would open the file in TextMate and jump to line 6. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's still relevant, but I've written a gem exactly for that. Works with textmate and sublime (requires additional software for the latter)

https://github.com/tadast/rspec_clickable_output

Comment: Thanks! I'm using RubyMine now as main editor, but my love for TM still hasn't gone completely.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for a way to do that with the Terminal, but I did not find it.

You can use [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). It's a real IDE that supports snippets, debugging and a lot more.

[image: RubyMine - Click on file path to open it]

I respect Textmate and I use it form time to time. But for a real developer environment with all that can be expected from it, RubyMine is the best so far.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked into RubyMine, but I'm just not an IDE-person, it seems. I liked Eclipse back in Java-time, but to me, it just doesn't feel right somehow to have such monsters running on my computer... ;)